# Incrementing certain values in "Tuples" in Python

Tags: python-3.x, hash, hashtable

Is there a way to increment a value for each distinct collision?

For example, I have a hash table [(1234, 1), (5678, 5), (2145, 7)] and I had a collision with 1234 and I want to update the entire tuple to (1234, 2). I found a way to do so, which is to initialise a variable called val = 0 but the problem is, it'll increment from where it left off.

```
def __init__(self, size):
    self.val = 0

def __setitem__(self, key, value):

    position = self.hash(key)
    j = 1

    for _ in range(self.table_size):
        #if there is nothing there, self.array[position] = (position, value)
        if self.array[position] is None:    
            self.array[position] = (position, value)
            self.count += 1
            return

        elif self.array[position][0] == self.hash(key):  
            #if there is an exisiting key and key == position, increment self.val
            self.val += 1
            self.array[position] = (position, self.val)
            self.collisions += 1
            return

        else:
            #if there's an existing key and key != position, find next available slot
            position = (position + j**2) % self.table_size
            j += 1
            self.collisions += 1
            self.count += 1
```

Basically I want the self.val to go back to where it left off for it's own key but I do not know how to do that without resetting it and making every key start from 0 again.

Comment: Tuples are immutable, you *can't replace values in them*. You can only replace the whole tuple.

Comment: yes, sorry. That's what I meant. I've edited the question.

Comment: Why not include the code of your attempt that doesn't work? It is far easier to help you with concrete code, even if it doesn't work. Make it a [MCVE], with input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: I've edited my code it, hopefully this suffices. Please let me know what I can do to make it better! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuples are not mutable in python, that's why you can't update the value. But also, that's not a hash table. Hashes are implemented as dictionaries in python. You can replace your structure by this:

```
d = {1234: 1, 5678: 5, 2145: 7}
```

Then you can do things like `d[1234] += 1` to increment the value.

Edit:

to conform with the restrictions of not using builtin types, you actually need to create a new tuple, since they are not mutable. But you should use the previous value you had in the tuple. It should look something like this:

```
 self.array[position] = (position, self.array[position][1]+1)
```

Comment: This is a manually implemented "hash table" wanted done by my uni. We're not allowed to use built-in functions and so this is just a make do to understand hash tables.

Comment: Then can you please post the code you already have? It's easier to help that way.

Comment: I've edited my code into my question, hopefully it's enough. Do let me know on any changes that needs to be done. Thank you!

Comment: I modified my answer to attend to your restrictions. Check if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: there was a slight error in the index, was supposed to be self.array[position] = (position, self.array[position][1]+1) but nevertheless, it worked!!! Thank you so much, Fernando!

Comment: I updated the code with the right index. Please remember to mark this as being the chosen answer.